# Trying to launch App Store - getting ""in something not a structure or union" error

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I am trying to launch the App Store without launching Safari with all the redirects and I am getting an error about "Request for member 'iTunesURL' in something not a structure or union."

I am new to a lot of this so thank you for being patient with me.  I think it has something to do with me calling "self.iTunesURL" since it doesn't think iTunesURL is a part of the current class, but I could be very wrong.

Thank you in advance for your help while I am (slowly) learning all of this.

SampleAppDelegate.h

```
-(void)launchStore:(NSURL *)iTunesURL;
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

SampleAppDelegate.m

```
// Process a LinkShare/TradeDoubler/DGM URL to something iPhone can handle
- (void)launchStore:(NSURL *)iTunesURL {

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:iTunesURL] delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
[conn release];
}

// Save the most recent URL in case multiple redirects occur
// "iTunesURL" is an NSURL property in your class declaration
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
self.iTunesURL = [response URL];
return request;
}

// No more redirects; use the last URL saved
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:self.iTunesURL];
}
```

MyViewController.h

```
#import "SampleAppDelegate.h"
```

and i have `NSURL *iTunesURL;` within the `@interface` curley braces.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *iTunesURL;

- (IBAction) proButtonPressed: (id)sender;  // press to launch App Store
```

MyViewController.m

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize iTunesURL;

- (IBAction) proButtonPressed: (id) sender {

NSURL *iTunesLink = [NSURL URLWithString:@"actual http URL goes here"];
SampleAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SampleAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate launchStore:iTunesLink];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iTunesURL` is a property of the `ViewController` class and you can only use the `self` reference within the methods of that class. Importing the `ViewController.h` class doesn't give the `SampleAppDelegate` class the ability to call the properties of `ViewController` class unless it is a subclass of `ViewController`.

You need to create a new another property within `SampleAppDelegate` and assign the value of `ViewController.iTunesURL` to that property.